# Azure Databricks Spark table from multiple files

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I have been able to create table on a single XML file like so

```
CREATE TABLE mytab
USING com.databricks.spark.xml
OPTIONS (
  path "/mnt/srcdir/myxmlfile.xml",
  rowTag "xmltag")
```

But I have multiple XML files in a directory and I want to load them all in single table 'mytab'. I tried the following and failed

```
CREATE TABLE mytab
USING com.databricks.spark.xml
OPTIONS (
  path "/mnt/srcdir/",
  rowTag "xmltag")
```

Below is a snippet of exception stacktrace

> Error in SQL statement: SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 9.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 17, 10.139.64.4, executor 0): java.io.FileNotFoundException: / is a directory not a file.
>           at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.open(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:2511)...

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Spark works at the directory level, and you can select the directory to read from the table.  All the files within the directory should be the same type and it will create a table based off the directory.

```
CREATE TABLE mytab
USING com.databricks.spark.xml
OPTIONS (
  path "/mnt/srcdir/",
  rowTag "xmltag")
```

> As a word of caution: "xmltag" is case sensitive.